# Python invalid syntax error (2.7.5)

Tags: python, syntax

```
clothes_total = tot1 + tot2 + tot3 + tot4+ tot5  
clothes_total1 = tot1 + tot2 + tot3+ tot4 + tot5
tot_price = tax * (clothes_total + shipping + gift_number)
tot_price1 = tax * (clothes_total1 * 0.85 + shipping + gift_number)
tot_price2 = tax * (clothes_total2 * 0.85 + shipping + gift_number - 30)
print "<h4>Original Price: $ %s </h4>" % clothes_total
if clothes_total < 150:
   print "<h4> TOTAL : %s </h4>" % tot_price
else clothes_total1 > 200:
  print "15% Discount + $30 off: $"
  print 0.85 * (clothes_total - 30)
  print "<h4> THIRTY: $ %s </h4>" % tot_price2
```

This is my line of code, but under `else clothes_total1 > 200:`, I keep getting:

> invalid syntax error

Don't know what the problem is. Can someone help me out help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `elif` not `else`:

```
elif clothes_total1 > 200:
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#):

```
if_stmt ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
             ( "elif" expression ":" suite )*
             ["else" ":" suite]
```

And instead of using `tot1 + tot2 + tot3 + tot4+ tot5`, I think you should use a list.

**Example:**

```
tot = [12,56,....] #some values
```

and then use `sum`:

```
clothes_total = sum(tot)
```

If the list has more than 5 items and you want sum of just first 5 items then use slicing:

```
clothes_total = sum(tot[:5])
```

Answer (score 1):

`else` cannot have predicate.

Use `elif` instead of `else`.

```
elif clothes_total1 > 200:
```

Answer (score 0):

`else` should be equal to `elif`.

This is because in Python, `else` acts as a kind of "catch-all"—it doesn't require any additional requirements, and in fact doesn't allow them. If you want to specify **conditions** for an else clause, then you have to use `elif`.

Comment: Python have no `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

else doesn't take a condition, but elif does.
If you use else, that means, if EVERYTHING fails, do this.